# Cannot access BIOS on Lenovo Z580

Tags: linux, windows-8, bios

Probably because of Windows 8 installation some time ago.
I know it is a common issue, however I am running Arch now and therefore cannot use most solutions.

I have access to Multiboot menu but when trying to go into BIOS, it just loads bootloader menu.

Is there a way to restore default access settings or force MB to open BIOS?

Comment: Did you do a complete format on the hdd before you installed the distro?

Comment: No, I don't think so. After installing Win8 I switched to Ubuntu and used dualboot with bootloader on Ubuntu. Now I have Arch + Ubu with same bootloader.

Comment: What Bootloader exactly

Comment: GRUB2, auto-configured under Ubuntu.

Comment: To interupt start up on a Lenovo you need to hit `Enter`. What happens if you tap that key while turning the computer on.

Comment: Nothing happened. I tried several times and I always end up in bootloader screen. Same if I press F2 (should get ne BIOS menu) - I see "Please wait..." message for second and then bootloader shows.